# Rails on Rubinius compiles assets very slowly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubinius

I'm trying to create a new Rails project using Rubinius (rbx-2.5.8) but it takes a while to compile stylesheet assets: More than 45 seconds after each change in some SCSS file... I didn't tested JS yet

Switching back to MRI (ruby-2.2.0) solves the problem (less than 3 seconds to compile). I didn't change the code, just the Ruby compiler using RVM.

Here are some information about my dev environment. Do you have any idea?

- Zeus server 0.15.4
- Puma 2.15.3
- Rails 4.2.5
- Rubinius 2.5.8
- sass 3.2.19
- sass-rails 4.0.5